# create JSON object in jquery, to many objects are created

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code that collects all information from a RSS feed, and takes out the information I need:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
    var stage = $(this).attr('p4:stage');
    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
    var desc = $(this).find('description').text();
    var location = $(this).find('category').eq[0];
    var billtype = $(this).find('category').eq[1];
    var linkurl = $(this).find('link').text();
    var thedate = $(this).find('a10\\:updated,updated').text();
    thedate = thedate.substring(0,10);

    info.push({'stage': stage},{'title': title},{'description': desc},{'location': location},{'billtype': billtype},{'linkurl': linkurl},{'thedate':thedate});


});

 console.log(info);
```

But when I look at what is being sent, its not 1 object with 5 children, each child representing a `<item>....contents.....</item>`, but one object with over 200 children, each one containing one part of the `<item></item>`, such as:

```
  [0 … 99]
    0: Object
      stage: "Committee stage"
      __proto__: Object
    1: Object
      title: "Mesothelioma"
      __proto__: Object
    2: Object
       description: "A Bill to establish a diffuse mesothelioma payments scheme and make related provision, and to make provision about the resolution of certain insurance disputes."
     __proto__: Object
```

Could someone help with the code, so I can get whatever number of rss feed items and it's contents to be a child ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: info is an array and you're pushing 7 objects into it for each 'item'.

Comment: I suspect you meant to do something like this:
`info.push({'stage': stage,'title': title,'description': desc,'location': location,'billtype': billtype,'linkurl': linkurl,'thedate':thedate});`

Comment: you have to define "info" as array and then use the below code to push the items in rows.
info[i].push(...)

Comment: @MasNotsram, yes you have to make the info as multi-dim array

Comment: So really I over did the curly brackets.  Thank you

Comment: When i pass this via jquery ajax to PHP, its coming up as [object Object], and php cannot see it as an object or an array.  What is it ?

Comment: If it's being passed via AJAX it's a string. It's a JSON String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place them in one object with 5 properties replace push function with:

```
info.push({
    'stage': stage,
    'title': title,
    'description': desc,
    'location': location,
    'billtype': billtype,
    'linkurl': linkurl,
    'thedate':thedate
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is, one object to be added to `info` array for each `item` element in the xml with the properties `stage, title, description, location, billtype, linkurl` and `thedate`

```
info.push({
    'stage' : stage,
    'title' : title,
    'description' : desc,
    'location' : location,
    'billtype' : billtype,
    'linkurl' : linkurl,
    'thedate' : thedate
});
```